# C++ File Handling

Tags: c++, file-io

I Googled around, but didn't find any good example / tutorial.

So i asking you SOF: How do you Read and Write to a File in C++?

Comment: If you could clarify what terms you used in Google, I'd be very interested in seeing what you missed...

Answer (score 4):

That is interesting.  I typed *How do you Read and Write to a File in C++* into google and found lots of results, like [this one](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files.html).

Answer (score 2):

A couple references to get you started:

- http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread6542.html
- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files.html

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen.html), [fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite.html), [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread.html), and [fclose](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fclose.html) functions for the most basic file I/O, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  FILE* f = fopen("hello world.txt", "wb");
  if(!f) return -1;
  fwrite("Hello World", sizeof(char), 11, f);
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

There are other functions that can help such as [fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fprintf.html), [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf.html), [fputs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fputs.html) and [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to do basic file-handling by yourself you might want to look at [The boost library](http://www.boost.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You might look at things like fprintf() and fscanf().  But to get you started:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

#define SHOW(X) cout << # X " = " << (X) << endl

void write()
{
  ofstream o("filefoo");
  o << "test 1 2 3" << endl;
}

void read()
{
  ifstream i("filefoo");
  string s[4];
  i >> s[0] >> s[1] >> s[2] >> s[3];

  for( int j=0; j<4; j++ )
    SHOW(s[j]);
}

int main()
{
  write();
  read();
}
```